# Why does the Installed Plugin SDKs not show up Under Liferay in the Liferay IDE Windows Preferences

Tags: eclipse, plugins, liferay-ide

I installed the Liferay IDE according to the following web site:

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/mvc/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-apps-with-liferay-ide

At the end of the instructions it says

Your runtime is now set up. Next, you need to register your Plugins SDK.

Select Window → Preferences → Liferay → Installed Plugin SDKs.

Click Add. Browse to the folder where you unzipped the Plugins SDK and click OK.

Click OK again.

But when I go to Windows -> Preferences -> Liferay, there is no Installed Plugin SDKs. Only the following:

Maven
Plugin Validation
XML Search

Comment: I have the same problem with Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)

Comment: I have the same problem with Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) –Liferay IDE
Latest release
3.0.1 (June 2016)

Comment: Same problem with Eclipse Neon! I am just wondering do I need this setup at all or not! I am following the setup wizard from [here | https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Getting+Started+Tutorial]

Answer (score 3):

I found out that the 3.0.0 M2 (March 2016) version of the Liferay-IDE release does not have that option in the Windows Preferences

I installed the Latest stable release (2.2.x) of the Liferay-IDE and the ability to setup the Plugins SDKs is available.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link - https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/72090414

Just create a new plugin project and choose the sdk during a new plugin project setup.